# WSL2 Ubuntu: How to start ssh-agent and add ssh key automatically on each terminal start up

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssh-agent

I'm using WSL2, on Terminal, with Ubuntu installed. I have added the following to my `.bashrc`:

```
# Start ssh-agent
# check if ssh-agent is already running
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
     #start ssh-agent
    eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
fi


# Ask for ssh-add
read -p "Do you want to add your SSH public key? (y/n) " response

if [ "$response" = "y" ]; then
  ssh-add ~/id_rsa
  ssh-add -l
elif [ "$response" = "n" ]; then
  echo "No identity on terminal session"
else
  echo "Invalid response"
fi
```

With the idea that every time I open a new terminal, it will ask for a prompt if an identity is needed and proceed to start ssh-agent and add the key if yes.
At first, it appears as if the script work and it'll show the agent's PID, along with a prompt for my ssh password and I'm able to see the ssh-agent when i do `top`. However, it did not actually initialize ssh-agent nor add the key, despite seeing the output of these commands.
I even did `ssh-add -l` and it'll output: `The agent has no identities.`

How do I go about making this work? This has to be a WSL issue..

Comment: Try using inside your `if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]` this: `ssh-agent -s > ~/.sshconnection` and in the `~/.bashrc` file (after the first if statement) use: `. ~/.sshconnection` or `source ~/.sshconnection`

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean to make these changes?:

` if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
      #start ssh-agent
     ssh-agent -s > ~/.sshconnection
 fi
 . ~/.sshconnection`

I've tested this one and it gives the same `stdout` as my previous entry, but still did not add my identity to the session.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?  Are you running WSL with Systemd or without?  Also, is there any difference if you start with `wsl ~ -e bash --norc --noprofile` and then run the commands manually?

Comment: Similar question with multiple answers: https://superuser.com/questions/1808572/how-to-automate-starting-the-ssh-agent-and-adding-my-keys-in-wsl2-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

Hum... you try to load `~/id_rsa`. Usually, keys are in the `~/.ssh` folder. AFAIR ssh is also very picky with file and folder permissions. If a key is in a directory that ssh thinks not secured enough, it won't use it.

If your key is really in `~`, move it (and the corresponding `.pub` file) into the `~/.ssh` folder. Make sure you own the files and the `~/.ssh` has `0700` mode, `~/.ssh/id_rsa` should have `0600` mode. See chmod(1) if you don't know how to do that.

Also, there's no need to give a filename to ssh-add. As per the man-page:

> `ssh-add` adds private key identities to the authentication agent, `ssh-agent(1)`. When run without arguments, it adds the files `~/.ssh/id_rsa`,
> `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk`, `~/.ssh/id_ed25519`, `~/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk`, and `~/.ssh/id_dsa`. After loading a private key, ...

in short :

- make sure your key files are in `~/.ssh` folder,
- in your `.bashrc` file just use `ssh-add`.

---

A quick note: Having questions in `.bashrc` is not necessarily a good thing. There exist situations (but maybe not in WSL) when `.bashrc` is loaded in non-interactive situations. If you really want to ask questions, read answers, protect the whole thing with a test on `PS1`

```bash
if test "$PS1"; then
  if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
    #start ssh-agent
    eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
  fi

  # Ask for ssh-add
  read -p "Do you want to add your SSH public key? (y/n) " response

  # and so on...
fi
```

---

EDIT NOTE:

I removed technical text that was not mine, but was added by someone else. Style, grammar, typos etc... corrections are always welcome. That someone adds **his/her** thoughts to **my** answer is not appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Thanks for that! I've added the test on PS1, I did not think of that so that's pretty good. Other than that, it seems no identity is still added :( my key was originally in a directory `src` which I've then moved to `.ssh` and just used `ssh-add` in `.bashrc`. I've also made sure they've got the correct permissions as you've mentioned. Not sure why it's still not adding the identity despite it saying it did when I open a new terminal.